# Is the development of market rate housing independent of the development of affordable housing?

Tags: macroeconomics, housing

Is the development of market rate housing independent of the development of affordable housing? Can anyone provide evidence that supports or refutes this?

Here is my thinking. While I have yet to find direct evidence for the affirmative, I did find [here](https://www.brookings.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/paganofinal.pdf) that:

> A recent survey examining vacant land and abandoned structures in 70 cities found that: On average, fifteen percent of a city's land was deemed vacant. This total includes widely varying types of land, ranging from undisturbed open space to abandoned, contaminated brownfields.

I also found [here](http://www.law.nyu.edu/sites/default/files/Been%20Ellen%20O%27Regan%20supply_affordability_Oct%2026%20revision.pdf) that:

> But it is not necessarily the case that the land where market-rate housing (or a mixture of market rate and affordable housing) is proposed would otherwise be used entirely for affordable housing. The land might continue to be too costly to support affordable housing, even if the land could not be used for housing for higher income households, because there are other uses (such as office or other commercial space) competing for the land. Also, the reasons affordable housing is not provided in larger quantities go far beyond the lack of land and include the inadequacy of funding to pay for construction, financing costs and operating costs.

This tells me that disallowing market rate housing may not create space for affordable housing, however does this really show independence of the two? This also tells me that there are other factors that affect the development of affordable housing besides land. Would the fact that these factors include "inadequacy of funding to pay for construction financing costs and operating costs" support the affirmative side of my question? I think they would unless it could be shown that market rate housing development affects these factors in affordable housing development, i.e., construction and operation costs.

Essentially, is there evidence that developing market rate housing necessarily comes at the consequence of the development of affordable housing?

I think that this comes down to simple economics, however, if this question belongs on a different Stack Exchange site, please let me know.

Comment: What are "market-rate" housing and "affordable" housing?

Comment: @KennyLJ Thank you, I probably should have pointed that out. In the United States, market rate housing is housing with no rent restrictions; market rate housing can be rented for whatever the market can bear. Affordable housing differs in the way that it must be deemed "affordable" by local governments. Affordability is chiefly determined by median income and affordability metrics. Affordable housing typically comes with rent controls and rent vouchers.

Comment: In the UK, where planning controls on land use are quite strict, it's certainly not independent.  Often a developer will only be granted permission to build homes on the condition that a defined proportion of the homes be affordable.

Comment: @AdamBailey That is a good point. I will concentrate my research there.

Comment: You should consider including the clarifications in response to KennyLJ in the body of the question.